# Inversion Symmetry in Periodic Lattices

Tags: topological-insulators, topological-phase

I am studying Short Course On Topological Insulator by J. K. Asboth, et.al.
In the context of inversion symmetry in section 3.2, the effect of inversion symmetry, $\Pi$, on the external degree of freedom of the wave function, i.e. $|k>$ is considered as $|k>\rightarrow|-k>$. However, in one dimension, $$|k>=\sum_m e^{imk}|m>$$
where $|m>$ specifies the unit cell and we expect $$\Pi|k>=\Pi\sum_m e^{imk}|m>=\sum_m e^{i(-m)k}|-m>\pi,$$ where $\pi$ represents the inversion operator on the internal Hilbert space. Also, it is clear that
$$|-k>=\sum_m e^{-imk}|m>.$$ Therefore, we observe that $$\Pi|k>\ne|-k>\pi$$ and so we can not consider the effect of inversion on $|k>$ as $|k>\rightarrow |-k>$!

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

$\Pi$ is a linear operator and $e^{\imath m k}$ is just a scalar, so it passes through $\Pi$ unaffected without changing the sign of the $m$.

Comment: Thank you, but according to your reasoning since $\psi(x)$ is scalar, it is unaffected by $\Pi$ while $\Pi \psi(x)=\psi(-x)$

Comment: $\Pi$ should act on elements of your Hilbert space, which if you are using a wavefunction notation means $\psi(x)$. One of the major advantages of Dirac notation is it makes the distinction between elements of the Hilbert space, scalars, matrix elements, etc. much clearer

Comment: Right, infact $\psi_a(x)$ is $<x|a>$ and so $\Pi <x|a>=<x|\Pi|a>=<-x|a>$. In the case of our argument, we also have $<m|k>=e^{ikm}$ and similarly, $\Pi<m|k>=<m|\Pi|k>=<-m|k>=e^{i(-m)k}$. Therefore, your reasoning seems not to be applied here.